# Batch File if command; is there any way to complete a certain task if a variable includes a certain character?

Tags: file, batch-file, if-statement

Ok, I have this batch file, and I would like to detect if the user's input includes a certain character, like `.`.

Here is what I have so far...

`IF /I %option%== ATTRIB +h`

(I would like it to detect if there is a `.` pressed)
I would like the `.bat` to detect If there is something other than `Attrib +h` pressed, like a `.`, for a file extension. So that if there was a file given, I would not ask for a file name again, because it wouldn't run properly!

Here is a part of the code, for Magoo.

```
@echo off
title iControl
color 80

:home
cls
echo iControl: Logan Murphy Version 1.5.7
echo Copyright 2014 Logan Murphy. All rights reserved.
GOTO jiki

:jiki
title iHelp
echo.
set /p "SSL=%USERNAME%>Execute>"
echo %SSL%"|find "." >nul
cls   
if errorlevel 1 (echo notfound) else (ATTRIB +h)
rem IMPLEMENTED IT HERE!
rem Here we go
rem need to fix execution
IF /I %SSL%==attrib goto attrib
IF /I %SSL%==pause goto pause
IF /I %SSL%==backup goto backup
```

Edit: Ok, the answers from magoo and john really helped, but if i wanted this to detect a folder name, as well as a file name, what would i change?

Edit: Ok Magoo, testing it now.

Edit: That doesnt really work well, as I am trying to find out if the variable INCLUDES a certain character, not if the whole variable is = to a valid file/folder name, but nice try. Will mess around with it a bit... Thanks for your time Magoo, I appreciate it:)

Edit: I think I worked it out! Thanks everyone who helped me!
Here is my new code...
@echo off

```
title iControl
color 80
:home
cls
echo iControl: Logan Murphy Version 1.5.7
echo Copyright 2014 Logan Murphy. All rights reserved.
GOTO jiki

:jiki
title iHelp
echo.
set /p "SSL=%USERNAME%>Execute>"
%SSL%
cls
goto Seconds

:Seconds
IF /I %SSL%==attrib goto attrib
IF /I %SSL%==attrib +h goto attrib+-
IF /I %SSL%==attrib -h goto attrib+-
IF /I %SSL%==attrib +r goto attrib+-
IF /I %SSL%==attrib -r goto attrib+-
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general formula would be

```
echo "%var%"|find "characterorstringrequired" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo notfound) else (echo found)
```

So, for your instance,

```
echo "%option%"|find "i" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo notfound) else (ATTRIB +h)
```

Beyond which, I have to be as vague as your question, I'm afraid...

---

After seeing part-code...

```
echo "%SSL%"|find "." >nul
cls   
if errorlevel 1 (echo notfound) else (ATTRIB +h)
```

I'm not sure whether `cls` affects errorlevel. The test should be executed directly after the command that establishes `errorlevel` - which is the `echo %SSL...` line.

```
echo "%SSL%"|find "." >nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo notfound) else (ATTRIB +h)
```

Serious damage can be done by `cmd` if the commands are not understood. The `attrib` command requires a target, so it should be

... else (attrib +h something)

to set `something` to hidden.

beyond that - it's not a good idea to use `cmd` keywords like `attrib`, `pause` and `backup` as labels. It can cause damage in the case of a tyop.

---

The benefit of sying *what* you want to do instead of *how* you want to do whatever-it-is.

To test for a file's existence, try

```
if exist "%SSL%" (echo "%SSL%" exists) else (echo "%SSL%" is not there)
```

where `echo` can be any legitimate (series of) command(s).

Comment: Sorry i wasnt that specific! I would just like to be able to detect if a certain character is pressed, in this instance a ".". For a file extension. I will test this, thx!

Comment: Hey Magoo, your script kinda messed up my computer, now all my files are hidden lol

Comment: So repeat the exercise but use `-h` in place of `+h` - shows why I use `echo(command` for testing...

Comment: Any reason why your code might not detect variable correctly? I have made sure that it is implemented correctly, goessing its something wrong with the code...

Comment: Ok, Here is my code, not sure if i implemented it corretly, i guess not, any help please?

Comment: @echo off

title iControl
color 80
:home
cls
echo iControl: Logan Murphy Version 1.5.7
echo Copyright 2014 Logan Murphy. All rights reserved.
GOTO jiki

:jiki
title iHelp
echo.
set /p "SSL=%USERNAME%>Execute>"
echo %SSL%"|find "." >nul
cls
if errorlevel 1 (echo notfound) else (ATTRIB -h)
rem Here we go
rem need to fix execution
IF /I %SSL%==attrib goto attrib
IF /I %SSL%==pause goto pause
IF /I %SSL%==backup goto backup
IF /I %SSL%==game goto game 
IF /I %SSL%==shutdown /p goto exec_shut
IF /I %SSL%==shutdown /h goto exec_shut
IF /I %SSL%==shutdown /l goto exec_shut

Comment: Hey Magoo, I think there is a small problem.

Comment: The code seems to work fine, but not for my usage. 'echo %SSL%"|find "." >nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo notfound) else (ATTRIB +h)'

Comment: So, i cant set the "something" as I would like to detect if there is a filename in the input, and without the batch fie testing the input, this cant be sorted properly

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this for all special chars ?

```
@echo off
:_Start
set /p "FID="
set FID="%FID:"=%"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%I in (^| ^& ^< ^> ^^ ^( ^) ' ` ^%% ^") do set FID=!FID:%%I=!
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set FID="%FID:!=%"
endlocal&set FID=%FID:~1,-1%
:_Back
set _Flag1=
for /f "tokens=1* delims=~=*;,?-+\/.@#${}[]:    " %%J in ('echo !FID!') do (
  set FID=%%J%%K
  set _Flag1=%%J
  set _Flag2=%%K
)
if NOT "%_Flag2%"=="" goto :_Back
if NOT defined _Flag1 goto :_Start
endlocal&set FID=%FID%
echo %FID%
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I am attempting to reconstruct a cmd like program in .bat. Any more commands you think i should take a look at? This helped a lot, thanks!

Comment: If you are attempting to write whole program with pure batch just dont. Because its not fast or usefull programming language like c/c#/c++. However if you want to have 'fun' you can try it. There are good games like "SokoBox" which is using batch. Btw if this post usefull vote up and/or click the check mark.

Answer (score -1):

The VBA command for finding a character in a string is INSTR so if you are looking for a . for example then in VBA could could use INSTR.  There are two ways to do what you want:

1. Write a QBASIC or VBscript version of INSTR and then call that from a BATCH script
2. Write a batch script that does INSTR.

If you are interested in the second one look at http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1986
It isn't as efficied as the first one would be because INSTR is pretty much a one liner in VBScript and the batch version does a character by character comparison, but if you are looking for a batch only solution that may do what you want.

Comment: I don't think the downvote was necessary.  He specifically asked about how to detect . and my solution does exactly that.